# Is there any way to restore EBS volume from snapshot using AWS CLI or CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

Is there a way to restore EBS volume from snapshot using AWS CLI or CloudFormation?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - please review the [guidelines on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CloudFormation you have [SnapshotId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volume.html#cfn-ec2-ebs-volume-snapshotid):

> The snapshot from which to create the volume. You must specify either a snapshot ID or a volume size.

In CLI you have [create-volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-volume.html#create-volume) where you can specify `--snapshot-id`.